# I'm getting duplicates even though I've filtered them out?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, discord

```html
(node:37532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: aio.users index: _id_ dup key: { _id: "751868484832460840" }
```

I'm getting this even after filtering out duplicates? I'm trying to make a user object for every user in every guild of my discord bot. Here's my code.

```html
aio.users.cache.forEach(async (user) =>{
        let userObject = await userList.find(uo => uo._id === user.id)
        if(!(userObject)){
            let newUser = await User.create({
                '_id': user.id,
                'username': user.tag,
                'avatarURL': user.avatarURL(),
                'description': `Hi! I'm ${user.username}!`,
                'accountcreated': user.createdAt
            })
            userList.push(newUser)
            globalGuild.markModified('users');
            return globalGuild.save();
        } return;
    })
```

In the db there isn't any objects even under user so it's not like there even is any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful when comparing `id`s. In the document-object returned from mongoose `_id` is most probably an instance of [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/). The `id` on the user is most probably a string, so comapring those with `===` will fail.

You can try doing:

```
let userObject = await userList.find(uo => uo._id.toString() === user.id)
```